# How to get cookies and post it while making HTTP post request for login in java

Tags: java, http, networking, cookies, request

i am trying to automate the login process using HTTPURLConnection (java) but while making HTTP POST request i need to post cookies also ..but how to get that cookies to post

i had first made an get http request on that login url and tried to get all header fields but from there also i am not getting cookies

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) instaL.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host","www.instagram.com");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Enocding","gzip, deflate, br");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","1");

       urlConnection.connect();

        Map<String, List<String>> header = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
        for (Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry : header.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("-------------Key "+key);
            for (String string : value){
                System.out.println("value = "+value);
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

i am not geeting cookies how to get it  so that i can use that and post it into POST request to login

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following manner.

If you are sending only one cookie, you have to do like this as given below.

```
String cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookie);
```

If you are sending multiple cookies, you have to do like this.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "name1=value1; name2=value2");
```